# Nested UITableVIew heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize performance and improve code quality.
I have the following layout:

```
OuterTableView
 Outer Cell
  UILabel (title label)
  InnerTableView
   Inner Cell (item cell)
   Inner Cell (item cell)
   ...
```

The purpose of this layout is expandable outer table. In collapse state only UILabel (only title label) is visible. When user clicks on outer cell, cell is expanded and reveals inner cells.

In **outer table controller** I have 3 functions (simplified):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        // ServiceGroupCell - outer cell
        ServiceGroupCell *serviceCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"service_group_cell"];
        [self configureCell:serviceCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return serviceCell;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void) configureCell:(ServiceGroupCell *) cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    // styling for outer cell and passing data for inner cells
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ServiceGroupCell *serviceGroupCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"service_group_cell"];
    [self configureCell:serviceGroupCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [serviceGroupCell layoutSubviews];

    CGFloat height = [serviceGroupCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    return height;
}
```

**Inner table controller**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [self.cellTableView layoutSubviews];
    // set height constraint for inner table view
    self.heightLayoutConstraint.constant = self.cellTableView.contentSize.height;
}
```

I have questions:
1) As you can see for each cell of outer table configureCell is invoked **twice**. Are there any ways to cache or just call it once?
2) systemLayoutSizeFittingSize returns 0. Are there any ideas why?

Comment: you want configureView to be called once ? did I understand your question ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD yes, I'd like to call configureCell once.

Comment: Are you sure self.tableView pointing on one table ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD yes, the main problem is in default call sequence for drawing cell: heightForRowAtIndexPath -> cellForRowAtIndexPath so the configureCell called twice

Answer (score 0):

> 2) systemLayoutSizeFittingSize returns 0. Are there any ideas why?

Your constraints are probably missing. Make sure you specify constraints for the width and height of the cell in the .xib file.

Answer (score -1):

Cells inner other cells is a bad idea, i think. You can make some sections, and using method didSelectRowAtIndexPath for when user tap on cell in section add cells to this section. Or use scrollview with custom nsview in which put tableview. Thats just work around.

Are there any ways to cache or just call it once? - try `willDisplayCell` method.